# Dashboard graph placement in Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

My, dashboard page of Shiny consists of three main rows.
My graphs in the first two rows works fine.

But wen it comes to the third row, I need to divide it mainly into two columns.
Then the first column need to be divided into other columns and place my pie chart in one column and radio buttons in another.

In the second large column, I need to place some info boxes. I tried placing this and following is the part related to my third row. But this doesn't work for me. Can someone please help.

```
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 8,

           splitLayout(
             column(width = 10,
                plotOutput("PieVaccineByGender", height = "350px", width = "700px")
             ),
                      
             column(width = 2,
                radioButtons(
                  "Vaccine",
                  "Enable or disable Grouping:",
                  c("Age" = "Age" ,
                    "Region" = "Region"),
                  inline = F
                )
                
               )
            ), 
        
      ),
    
    column(width = 4,
           infoBoxOutput('VaccineCount')
           )
  )
```

Following is how my dashboard looks now.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The info box is not the right display? try `width = 12`

Why do you need to use `splitLayout`? You can directly add columns inside a column

see below

```r
library(shinydashboard)
library(shiny)
shinyApp(
    ui = dashboardPage(
        dashboardHeader(),
        dashboardSidebar(),
        dashboardBody(
            fluidRow(
                column(width = 8,
                       column(width = 10,
                              plotOutput("PieVaccineByGender", height = "350px", width = "700px")
                       ),
                       
                       column(width = 2,
                              radioButtons(
                                  "Vaccine",
                                  "Enable or disable Grouping:",
                                  c("Age" = "Age" ,
                                    "Region" = "Region"),
                                  inline = F
                              )
                              
                       )
                ),
                
                column(width = 4,
                       shinydashboard::infoBox(title = "abc", value = "123", icon = icon("exclamation-triangle"), width = 12)
                )
            )
        ),
        title = "Dashboard example"
    ),
    server = function(input, output) { output$PieVaccineByGender <- renderPlot(plot(1))}
)
```

[image: screenshot1]